# PHP doesn't follow if..else conditions

Tags: php

I have this working website yet I got a problem with the following lines of code:

```
<?php

//CREATION OF CONNECTION

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbJobsheets");

//CHECKING OF CONNECTION

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$checker = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT colActualStart FROM tblChecklist WHERE colEntryID='1' AND colDate='Aug 19,2014'");

if ($checker != NULL) {
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tblChecklist WHERE colEntryID='1'");

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<center><table border=0 width=100><font face=arial>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['colActualStart'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "</font></table></center>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<div class=\'buttonX\'><input type=button value=\"Enabled\" id=clickY onClick=action2(); style=\"left:10;\"></div>";
    echo "<div class=\'textY\'><input type=text id=as1 value=\'\' style=\"visibility:\'hidden\'; width:120px;\">";
}

?>
```

Everything is working up until the `$checker` mark; what I want with is for the system to check if the corresponding colActualStart entry for the corresponding `colEntryID` and `colDate` is null or not. If its null, it should run the commands inside the if tag, else if not.

The problems seems to be in the `$checker`, since the entire line of code is inside the `$checker` variable, it is not null; that is why the code is running the if commands. It doesn't fetch the data inside the `colActualStart` column and convert to string to be really able to check if its null or not.

Comment: `It doesn't fetch the data inside the colActualStart column and convert to string to be really able to check if its null or not` You already know the problem.

Comment: -1 for a really really misleading and false title.

Comment: Why'd you escape single quotes inside of double quotes under the else block…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check value of `colActualStart` by checking the result of the `mysqli_query`.

After your `mysqli_query`, your must call a fetch function to retrieve data, like you did 2 lines below.

A something like that and it will work :

```
$checker=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT colActualStart FROM tblChecklist WHERE colEntryID='1' AND colDate='Aug 19,2014'"));
    if($checker[0] != NULL){
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked, thank you for answering my question rather than hitting the -1 for certain technicalities.